# generic / central popViewControllerAnimated method

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a sweet little question and scenario:

Question: can I have the [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:True]

being controlled from a central class insted of having to be repeated in every view.

so this is what I have so far:
the view:

```
//this is all I want to accomplish and repeat in every view. I want to pass on the own NavigationController and have central class add an action (and style) to the leftBarButton

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[actionsCollection setGenericBackButton:self.navigationController]];
```

central class:

```
@interface ActionsCollection ()
@property(nonatomic, weak)UINavigationController *NavCtrl; // I do this since I dont seem to be able to pass the self.NavigationController on to the buttons action selector (se bellow).
@end
```

setGenericBackButton does:

```
-(UIBarButtonItem *)setGenericBackButton:(UINavigationController *)NavContrl{
     _NavCtrl = NavContrl; // so that I can get a the global (to the class) UINavigationController being reached from -(IBAction)backButtonAction (see bellow)

     UIButton* myBackButton = [ButtonMaker BtnTypeBack]; //just returns a styled btn

//this is where it starts to fail - I want to pass the 'NavContrl' on with the selector bunt havnt figured out how (thats why the global variable '_NavContrl'
    [myBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem* BackBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myBackButton];

}
```

backButtonAction does:

```
-(IBAction)backButtonAction{
     [_NavCtrl popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

Am I lazy for trying to save lines of code trying to do the impossible or can this actually be done?
I am more than happy to explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

Good programmers are lazy.

That said, if you set up UINavigationController properly it will add its own back buttons and do this for you. You shouldn't need any code beyond `[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: thingy is that I need to use the leftBarButton since I am creating a button of my own. So while I am creating the button I want at the same time to be able to put code snippet you mention on it and thats why I want to attach the views NavigatorController over to my little button machinery class :) would save me implementation of codes in every view with UINavigatiorController

Comment: If you are supporting iOS 5 or later you should look at UIAppearance.

Specifically:  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];